Ubuntu 24.04: netplan: bond0 works when activated manually, but not at boot
I'm trying to configure a bond interface using netplan. It works after a manual "netplan apply", but doesn't come up at boot. My netplan config:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
[...]
        enp86s0f0np0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            addresses: []
        enp86s0f1np1:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            addresses: []
[...]
    bonds:
      bond0:
        mtu: 9000
        interfaces:
          - enp86s0f0np0
          - enp86s0f1np1
        dhcp4: false
        dhcp6: false
        addresses:
          - A.B.C.D/24 (REDACTED)
        routes:
[...]
        parameters:
          mode: 802.3ad
          lacp-rate: fast
          transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
          mii-monitor-interval: 100

Networkd logs show this at boot time:
Sep 09 10:14:53 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: bond0: netdev ready
Sep 09 10:14:53 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: Enumeration completed
Sep 09 10:14:53 host1 systemd[1]: Started systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit systemd-networkd.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit systemd-networkd.service has finished successfully.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 144.
[...]
Sep 09 10:15:00 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp10s0f7np7: Configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp10s0f7np7.network.
Sep 09 10:15:01 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f0np0: Configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp86s0f0np0.network.
Sep 09 10:15:01 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f1np1: Configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp86s0f1np1.network.
Sep 09 10:15:02 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f2np2: Configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp86s0f2np2.network.
[...]
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: bond0: Failed to wait for the interface to be initialized: Connection timed out
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: bond0: Failed
[...]
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp10s0f7np7: Link UP
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f0np0: Link UP
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f1np1: Link UP
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f2np2: Link UP
[...]
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f0np0: Gained carrier
Sep 09 10:15:19 host1 systemd-networkd[1955]: enp86s0f1np1: Gained carrier

It looks to me like its trying to bring up bond0 before its slaves gained carrier (enp86s0f0np0, enp86s0f1np1). This isn't normal is it? How can I avoid this? Anything else I can check?
Edit 2024-09-12 - as a workaround I disabled netplan & networkd, and configured the interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces (Ubuntu 24.04)
